# Socat command syntax

Tags: linux, shell, socat

Here is some socat command example I find:

```
$ printf "md.b 0x0800000 0x100000\r\r" | \
socat - /dev/ttyUSB0,raw,echo=0,crnl >u-boot.ascii 2>&1
```

It's not clear what is purpose of backslash "\" after vertical bar: does it just artifact (separator) applied by mail client or it has some meaning? The command need be in one line probably?

Answer (score 2):

That's a way to split a line into more lines. The literal meaning of the backslash is escaping the end of line symbol. The effect is that the line is not ending where it does, but it continues on the next line. As can be guessed, the end of line symbol has to follow the `\` immediately. If there's a space after the backslash, it won't work.